# KeystoneJS com Mongo remoto

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

Boa noite!

Estou começando a estudar [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com/) `versão 0.3.17`. Seguindo o ["Getting started"](http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/) do site oficial, nos pré requisitos pede-se [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) e o [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/), porem quero usar esse [serviço cloud](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud) do [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/).

Como poderia fazer essa integração? É possível? Pois, não instalei o [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/) em meu computador e quando vou executar o comando `node keystone` acontece esse erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Edit**: Para conexão remota o [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com/) disponibiliza no arquivo `.env` a propriedade `MONGO_URI=mongodb://your-server/database-name`

Testei a conexão remota pelo `command line` usando esse comando: `mongo "mongodb://***-shard-00-00-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017,***-shard-00-01-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017,***-shard-00-02-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=***-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username *** --password ***`, a conexão é feita com sucesso.

Quando configuro a propriedade `MONGO_URI` no `.env`, dessa forma: `MONGO_URI=mongodb://***:***@***-shard-00-00-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017,***-shard-00-01-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017,***-shard-00-02-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=***-shard-0&authSource=admin`, é retornado um erro de autenticação.

Estou usando exatamente as mesmas credenciais e nomes do banco e replica.

> **Edit**: O problema estava nos caracteres da senha usada. Não seu por qual motivo mas a senha não pode ter o caractere "@" nessas condições de conexão.

Comment: Aparentemente ele está tentando se conectar ao mongo do localhost. Você já tentou alterar a URI do mongo?

Dê uma olhada no fim desta página: http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/

Comment: Leonardo, a solução estava a "um scroll do mouse" rsrs. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ainda assim não esta dando certo, peguei o link de conexão no cloud mongodb atribui ao `MONGO_URI` com o login e a senha e o `database` corretos, e retorna `authentication fail` ou se eu deixo a uri como no exemplo do site do `keystonejs` ( `MONGO_URI=mongodb://your-server/database-name` me retorna connection closed.

Comment: Hmm, de uma olhada aqui: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/, veja se o formato da URI esta certa.

Comment: Esta correto, olha como estou usando a `URI` (`mongodb://******:******@*******-shard-00-00-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017,*******-shard-00-01-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017,*******-shard-00-02-nalfi.mongodb.net:27017/*******-shard-00-00-nalfi?ssl=true&replicaSet=*******-shard-0&authSource=admin`).

Mas já tentei várias formas de `ÙRI` e todos retornam erro.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Se não, posta o código que você está usando aí pra galera... :p

Comment: @Blogueira minha senha tinha um "@" isso que estava dando problema. Alterei para letras e números somente e agora está normal. Obrigado pessoal!